# Integrate sensor_msgs with ros 2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a pub-sub using sensor_msgs in ros 2? Is there tutorial showing how to do this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271440/integrate-sensor_msgs-with-ros-2-?/) by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the listener and talker under demo_node_cpp. If you don't have repositories look here https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Ament-Tutorial.

Change the message and include your sensor message type, and use as in ROS 1.

Also, check this Imu listener: https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/imu_listener.cpp

e.g. if sensor messages from Joint State of a robot

```
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/joint_state.hpp"

const sensor_msgs::msg::JointState state;
```

should be the message type.

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1